# Determine Number of Minutes Worked By Hour worked When Beginning and Ending Time Are in Different Hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:
HourList - has every hour of the day in a field:  hour
LoginLogout - has employees and when the login and out

I'm trying to adapt code from an answer that did it in MySQL, but having all sorts of problems, from the CASE statement, to the timeadd conversion to dateadd.  I really believe this MySQL code does exactly what I want, I just don't have the chops to convert it to SQL on my own.  Here was the code for MySQL ... mine is a mess and not worth posting.

```
select hour, userid,
case
   when login < hour and logout >= ADDTIME(hour,'1:00:00.0') then '1:00:00.0'
   when login >= hour and logout < ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0')then TIMEDIFF(logout, login)
   when login >= hour and logout > ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0') then TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0'), login)
   when login < hour and logout < ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0') then TIMEDIFF(logout, hour)
   else '00:00:00.0'
end case
from hourlist join loginlogout
on (login >= hour and login < ADDTIME(hour,'1:00:00.0')) or (logout >= hour
and logout < ADDTIME(hour,ADDTIME(hour,'1:00:00.0'))
order by hour
```

Sorry for bad posting protocol or anything else I messed up, first time posting.  Thanks in advance.

---Don't know if I'm getting closer or not ... but here's what I've got based on everyone's feedback.  It's still erroring out ...

```
select hourlist.hour, employeelabor.empposid,
    case 
when employeelabor.clockin < hourlist.hour and employeelabor.clockout >= dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) then '1:00:00.0'
when employeelabor.clockin >= hourlist.hour and employeelabor.clockout < dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) then datediff(mi,employeelabor.clockout, employeelabor.clockin)
when employeelabor.clockin >= hourlist.hour and employeelabor.clockout > dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) then datediff(mi,1,dateadd(mi,hourlist.hour,1))
when employeelabor.clockin < hourlist.hour and employeelabor.clockout < dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) then datediff(mi, hourlist.hour, employeelabor.clockout)
    else '00:00:00.0'
end 
MinWorked
from hourlist
    JOIN dbo.employeelabor
        on (employeelabor.clockin >= hourlist.hour and employeelabor.clockin < dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) 
        or (employeelabor.clockout >= hourlist.hour
        and employeelabor.clockout < dateadd(hh,hourlist.hour,dateadd(hh,hourlist.hour,1))
order by hourlist.Hour
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of your columns?

Comment: You mention that this is MySQL syntax, but what is the target DBMS? SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Teradata?

Comment: target Database is SQL

Comment: hour, login, logout are all time(7)

Comment: Sql,yes, but **whose** SQL. There are tons of SQL implementations and date/time types and handling vary wildly from one implementation to another. What specific database system are you targeting?

Comment: Sorry for being vague.  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.  many thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax for these functions:

`DATEADD(HH, 1, [hour])`

The HH is for hours, and you're adding 1 hour to the DateTime in the [hour] column.

`DATEDIFF(mi, [hour], [logout])`

The mi is for minutes.

`CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`

This is pretty much the same as mysql.

Comment: in SQL, the CASE requires you to say which column ... whereas in MySQL it doesn't.  How would that look in MSSQL?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the CASE requires you to say which column.' SQL Server handles it the same way as MySQL, here is part of your CASE, translated:

`case when login < hour and logout >= DATEADD(HH, 1, [hour]) then 60 end`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server (Transact-SQL), assuming `hour`, `login` and `logout` are datatype `TIME`...

The rough equivalent to MySQL `ADDTIME(foo,'1:00:00')` would be

```
DATEADD(HOUR,1,foo)
```

And the rough equivalent to MySQL `TIMEDIFF(bar,foo)` in SQL Server 2008 or later, would be

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND,foo,bar)
```

This expression will return an integer number of seconds (the number of "boundaries" crossed).  To get that formatted as a string in `hh:mm:ss` format, you'd need to use integer division and modulo functions. For example:

```
FLOOR(integer_seconds / 3600)        = whole hours
FLOOR((integer_seconds % 3600) / 60) = remainder whole minutes 
FLOOR(integer_seconds % 60)          = remainder whole seconds
```

To get the minutes and seconds formatted to two characters, you could cast the integer value to `VARCHAR`, prepend a '0' character, and take the rightmost two characters.

Alternatively, to get integer seconds formatted, you could take the value, at it to some dummy datetime value (midnight), to get a `datetime`, and then `CONVERT`  that to VARCHAR using a style that gets you the format you want. (You might need to use a canonical/fixed format style (like 20?) `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"`, and use a string function (SUBSTR or RIGHT) to "lop off" the date part.)